# Carousel to be the same size as image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a gallery when an image is clicked on it brings up a carousel.

I'm almost there, but the image is huge when full size so I need it to be smaller however it leaves a background on the carousel.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row>.column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: black;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpg" style="width:300px" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M19Z4BO.png" style="width:300px" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9O8BzsM.jpg" style="width:300px" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UJTT5GK.jpg" style="width:300px" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpg" style="width:300px">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M19Z4BO.png" style="width:300px">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9O8BzsM.jpg" style="width:300px">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UJTT5GK.jpg" style="width:300px">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="../window/img/img1.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="../window/img/img2.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="../window/img/img3.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="../window/img/img4.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image of what happens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoHAj.jpg

As you can see in the image, the photo isn't within the next/previous arrows and there's a lot of empty space (red) when it should just shrink/grow to the size of the image.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why you are can't use bootstrap carousel ?

Comment: @RayeesAC not everyone uses bootstrap, and it would be a bit silly to load the whole of bootstrap just for one feature. Focus on the actual problem in this code instead.

Comment: You want to put big image between left right arrows? Like left arrow on left-margin, right arrow on right-margin and center image?

Comment: I'm wanting the image between the arrows but also the container to fit the image size so there's no extra space (red) space.

Comment: But our container is big rectangle. How could you fit sqare/circular images inside it perfectly? Do you want fill effect? I don't think it look nice

Comment: We can't set container to fit the image size. If we do that, then our left and right arrows change position with different image sizes, which would be really frustrating. I think current size is best with black background instead of red one.

Comment: can you post the actual images so we can run your snippet? there's an image upload button..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I wonder even on stack-overflow people target each-other. My only fault is that I put my code inside Jackawan erroneous code for his easiness. For that I received down-vote by jrswgtr. Plus when I asked Jackawan about the answer I posted I get complete ignorace. Is this the way developer community get motivated here? Even after removing his code, still I am on down-vote. Pic of Jackawan erroneous code https://upload.picpaste.me/image/kNpZ9

Comment: @gpl the issue with your original snippet was that you had the javascript in the header and didn't use an onload callback. next time just click the "copy snippet to answer" button instead of rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Till now I used to copy paste it in my editor for debugging  Thank you. I will use that button from now on. Helpful Expert Devs like you are great for new devs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS style:

```css
        .modal-content .mySlides img{
            display:block;
            margin:auto;
        }
```

It will center the image. Further move `<a class="prev">` before `<div class="mySlides">` to place it on left-margin.

Comment: If you post a code snippet, at least make sure it works

Comment: Well, click "Run snippet" at the second one and see for yourself! (showing an error message)

Comment: Yes it is working. First read the question. I have added the new CSS rules to the code provided by Jackawan. This Javascript error is generated by his code. But this error isn't  his problem. Problem is to place Slide image between the arrow buttons. I wonder why I get downvote for giving right answer. He is also not responding. I even asked him if he tried it or not.

Comment: no matter if the error is not the problem. It's just ugly to post a snippet with errors. Also the original OP's snippet does not show the same error so it's because of something you changed to it

Comment: Then I remove it away. I pasted it for Jackawan's easiness. Its his code which generating errors not mine.

Comment: Well it's not, check the OP's snippet. No errors there

Comment: who is OP? Code provided by Jackawan producing errors.

Comment: OP is "Original Poster" Jackawan. Run the snippet in his question and you will see no error message

Comment: I runned it and seeing error mesage. You need to run it porperly. See this image: https://upload.picpaste.me/image/kNpZ9

Comment: i updated op's snippet with actual images. adding this css at the bottom of the stylesheet does indeed solve the stated problem. this is the correct answer.